# Java catch being ignored

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm breaking my head with this:

```
protected void setParameters(HttpServletRequest request) {

    try {
        page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("p"));
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
        messages.add("Invalid page.");
    }

    try {
        status = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("s"));
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
        messages.add("Invalid status.");
    }

}
```

Before I placed this method into a super class it was working as expected; but now when I have a query string without the p parameter (for example), the exception (NumberFormatException) is thrown (as expected), then caught by the first catch (as expected) and then rethrown and caught by the calling function (this is not expected). Since the exception was already caught here, the execution should just continue.

I'm attaching a screenshot where you can see:

- in pink: my breakpoint
- in green: my current execution line
- as a balloon: the current type of the exception which clearly says it is a NumberFormatException

[image]

Any ideas are very appreciated

**Update:**

Thank you, this is my calling stack: Servlet > UserListHandler > setParameters

UserListHandler() is a contructor and looks like this:

[image]

Servlet looks like this:

[image]

I find interesting that the exception the servlet is catching is a NullPointerException.

The top of my stack trace looks like this:

```
Mar 31, 2014 5:13:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [UserListServlet] in context with path [/App.Web] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Can you show the calling code and any evidence that it catches the handled exception too?

Comment: Where does your stack trace indicates your exception was raised?

Comment: Evidently somewhere else is also throwing an exception. The first exception, the one in the screen shot, it won't escape the catch block. If another one is being caught somewhere it means there are two exceptions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone... Yes, there was a null pointer exception because there was a variable that was never initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that there is another exception.

Maybe "messages", inside the catch is null and it is throwing a new NullPointerException?

Comment: I feel so stupid!, thank you so much @Alfcope, messages was never instantiated. And thanks to everyone else too!

Comment: Things happen. I think everybody has made the same error at least once.